# pyspark implementation of difflib.get_close_matches

Tags: pyspark, difflib

Is there any pyspark equivalent function for difflib.get_close_matches. My Dataset is huge and wanted to compare and get the close match. I am not able to broadcast the compared dataset as it is not iterable.

Comment: have you found a workaround?